# Find ratio of duplicate values in a field b/w every 2 users. (MySQL)

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, database, report

I want to generate a complex report on a single database table (MYSQL) for User_Hits. Here is the table structure with sample data.

```
    TABLE: User_Hits
User_ID      IP_Address
1            192.168.1.1
1            192.168.1.2
1            192.168.1.3
1            192.168.1.4
2            192.168.1.2
2            192.168.1.4
2            192.168.1.50
2            192.168.1.55
3            192.168.1.2
3            192.168.1.55
3            192.168.1.111
```

And here is the report output I want to get.

```
Percentage of duplicate IPs b/w every two Users

USER     1        2        3
  1     -       50%      25%
  2     50%       -       50%
  3     33.3%   66.6%      -
```

Values of each cell are based on following example calculation:
For Example, 66.6% is calculated as:

```
= (Number of IPs common b/w User 3 and User2) * 100 / (Number of IPs for User3 )
= (2 * 100) / 3
= 66.6
```

Every cell in the report is calculated the same way.

Is it possible to generate this report by using MYSQL queries only ?
Anyone has ever generated this kind of report... Please guide me, I need help from SQL experts.

I have built schema for **User_Hits** in [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/213b2/1) so you can write query herein directly.

Thanks

Comment: Do the pivot bit in your presentation layer. Everything else is a simple GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this if this could help you

```
SELECT DISTINCT u3.User_ID,
    t.U2UserID,
    COUNT(u3.IP_Address) Totalcount,
    IPCount
FROM (SELECT
    u1.User_ID U1UserID,
    u2.USER_ID U2UserID,
    COUNT(u1.IP_Address) IPCount
FROM user_Hits u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_Hits u2

    ON u1.User_ID <> u2.USER_ID
    AND u1.Ip_Address = u2.IP_Address
GROUP BY    u1.User_ID,
        u2.USER_ID) t
INNER JOIN User_Hits u3
    ON t.U1UserID = u3.User_ID
GROUP BY    u3.User_ID,
        IPCount,
        t.U2UserID
```